# Stuck with ATBS with python Conway's Game of Life

Tags: python, python-3.x

At chapter 4 Lists in the book ATBS with python there is a short program: Conway's Game of Life. As far as I can see I copied the code exactly. When I run the code it gives no error messages. But I only see spaces appearing. I am using the Mu editor software as indicated in the book.

Could someone copy and paste my code and see if they do get more to be than spaces?

Below is the code:

```
# Conway's Game of Life
import random, time, copy
WIDTH = 60
HEIGHT = 20

# Create a list of list for the cells:
nextCells = []
for x in range(WIDTH):
    column = []  # Create a new column
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        if random.randint(0, 1) == 0:
            column.append('#')  # add a living cell
        else:
            column.append(' ')  # add a dead cell
    nextCells.append(column)  # NextCells is a list of a column lists.
    
while True:  # Main program loop
    print('\n\n\n\n\n')  # Seperate each step with newlines
    currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)
    
# Print currentCells on the screen:
for y in range(HEIGHT):
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        print(currentCells[x][y], end='')  # Print the # or space
    print()  # Print a newline at the end of the row

# Calculate the next step's cells based on current steps cells:
for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
        # Get neighboring coordinates:
        # '% WIDTH' ensures leftCoord is always between 0 and WIDTH -1
        leftCoord = (x - 1) % WIDTH
        rightCoord = (x + 1) % WIDTH
        aboveCoord = (y - 1) % HEIGHT
        belowCoord = (y + 1) % HEIGHT
        
        # Count number of living neighbors
        numNeighbors = 0
        if currentCells[leftCoord][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # Top-left neighbor is alive
        if currentCells[x][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # Top neighbor is alive
        if currentCells[rightCoord][aboveCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # Top-right neighbor is alive
        if currentCells[leftCoord][y] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # Left neighbor is alive
        if currentCells[rightCoord][y] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # Right neighbor is alive
        if currentCells[leftCoord][belowCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # below-left is alive
        if currentCells[x][belowCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # below is alive
        if currentCells[rightCoord][belowCoord] == '#':
            numNeighbors += 1  # below-right is alive
        
        # Set cell based on Conway's Game of Life rules:
        if currentCells[x][y] == '#' and (numNeighbors == 2 or numNeighbors == 3):
            # Living cells with 2 or 3 neighbors stay alive:
            nextCells[x][y] = '#'
        elif currentCells[x][y] == ' ' and numNeighbors == 3:
            # Dead cells with 3 neighbors become alive:
            nextCells[x][y] = '#'
        else:
            # Everything else dies or stays dead
            nextCells[x][y] = ' '

time.sleep(1)  # add a 1 second pause to reduce flickering
```

What is the fault in my code?

Comment: You have failed to copy the appropriate indentation. Check the comment near the first `while True:` loop, it may give you a hint.

Comment: Thanks for your replay Captian Trojan, unfortunetly I dont know what you meen. This pice of code is exactly the same as staded in the book.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is the fact that everything after the first `while True:` statement should be inside the loop, however, the indentation in your code (which defines scopes in Python) causes the loop scope to only span 2 lines, instead of the whole remainder of the file.

The solution would be to add a `[TAB]` at the beginning of every line of code after

```
while True:  # Main program loop
    print('\n\n\n\n\n')  # Seperate each step with newlines
    currentCells = copy.deepcopy(nextCells)
```

so that

```
for x in range(WIDTH):
    for y in range(HEIGHT):
```

et cetera turns to

```
    for x in range(WIDTH):
        for y in range(HEIGHT):
```

and so on. If you use an appropriate code editor or an IDE, you should be able to select all such lines and press `[TAB]` on your keyboard to fix the problem.

I can also see that the book you mentioned has the source code in perfect condition, so the author must have fixed the issue already.